# Swapping the numbers in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I am trying to create a method that will accept the users input for the amount of elements they would like in an array, and the numbers to input for the array.

So far I have the main method which accepts the input from the console using the following code, after that I am not 100% sure if the method I need to create should return an int array or should just print out the results.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input amount desired in Array 1");`
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int [] array1 = new int[a];

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Input a number");
                        array1[i] = input.nextInt();}
    System.out.println();}
```

`public int swapPairs(int [] array)`

Comment: `I am not 100% sure if the method I need to create should return an int array or should just print out the results.` It totally depends on how you want to implement it. You could return your `array` from your `swapPairs` method or simply swap the numbers and print the result inside your `swapPairs` method.

Comment: I would carefully read your instructions.  If it really doesn't say, I would lean towards your method returning the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so You just do this:

```
public void swapPairs(int [] array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i += 2){
        if(i != array.length - 1)
        System.out.print(array[i] + " " + array[i+1]);
    }
if(array.length % 2 == 1) System.out.print(" " + array[array.length - 1]);
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using the your coding and changing it around to what i need. 

Here is what I was looking for

`public static void swapPairs(int [] array){ `
`for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i+=2){`
`System.out.println(" " + array[i+1] + " " + array[i] + " "); } }`

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake, of course I was meant to write it other way which is first array[i+1] and then array[i] :D but I'm glad you got it and changed it

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to achieve. If you need only to see the results the print is enough but if you return the array you can operate on the one that is changed as you wanted

Comment: I want to be able to just print out the results.  What I am needing is to have the 1st and second place swap, then the 3rd and 4th, and so on and so on.